# Reverse JQuery Range Slider Handlers

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am working on a Range Slider, where i wanted to reverse the ranges in the slider on button click. I have almost done the basic, but i am confused with the calculation of the slider handles being working after swapping the values in text box.

I have posted the code in fiddle.

*** JQuery Click Handler for reversing values***

```
$("#reversePassFailVal").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    sliderElement.slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#minValue").val(9-ui.values[0]);
      $("#maxValue").val(5-ui.values[1]);
    }

  })
    $("#minValue").val(sliderElement.slider('values', 1));
  $("#maxValue").val(sliderElement.slider('values', 0));
});
```

***HTML***

```
<form id="form1">
    Caution Range: 
    <span id="cautionVal"/>
    <br/>
    <div id="slider"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="txtPassRange">Pass Range</label>
    <input type="text" id="minValue"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="txtFailRange">Fail Range</label>
    <input type="text" id="maxValue" />
    <br/>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="reversePassFailVal">Inverse</a>
</form>
```

You can find the code in this 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xw7t4c1r/23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to destroy the slider on each change of range.

I don't know if this is the optimum solution, but here I'm building a  slider on load of the page and then destroying it on button click and creating a  fresh slider which we'd use till the page is reloaded.

The code needs optimizations and I'm open to it. Please suggest them in the comments below.

**HTML:** (Notice #Slider1)

```
<form id="form1">
  Caution Range: <span id="cautionVal"></span>
  <br /><br />
  <div id="slider"><br /></div>
  <div id="slider1"></div><br />
  <label for="txtPassRange">Pass Range</label>
  <input type="text" id="minValue" />
  <br /><br />
  <label for="txtFailRange">Fail Range</label>
  <input type="text" id="maxValue" />
  <br /><br />
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="reversePassFailVal">Inverse</a>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cautionValue = $("#cautionVal");
  var flag = 0;
  var sliderElement = $("#slider");
  var sliderElement1 = $("#slider1");
  $("#slider").slider({
    range: true,
    steps: 0.01,
    values: [5, 9],
    min: 0,
    max: 24,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      cautionValue.html(ui.values[0] + '-' + ui.values[1] + 'km/lo');
      $("#minValue").val(ui.values[0]);
      $("#maxValue").val(ui.values[1]);
    },

  });
  cautionValue.html(sliderElement.slider('values', 0) + '-' + sliderElement.slider('values', 1) + 'km/lo');
  $("#minValue").val(sliderElement.slider('values', 0));
  $("#maxValue").val(sliderElement.slider('values', 1));

  // Inverse Click Handler
  $("#reversePassFailVal").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#slider').length) {
      sliderElement.slider("destroy");
      sliderElement.remove();
    } else {
      sliderElement1.slider("destroy");
    }
    var maxVal = $("#maxValue").val();
    var minVal = $("#minValue").val();
    var minRange = 0;
    var maxRange = 24;
    if (flag === 0) {
      maxVal = maxVal * -1;
      minVal = minVal * -1;
      minRange = -24;
      maxRange = 0;
    }
    sliderElement1.slider({
      range: true,
      steps: 0.01,
      values: [maxVal, minVal],
      min: minRange,
      max: maxRange,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (flag === 0) {
          cautionValue.html(Math.abs(ui.values[0]) + '-' + Math.abs(ui.values[1]) + 'km/lo');
          $("#minValue").val(Math.abs(ui.values[1]));
          $("#maxValue").val(Math.abs(ui.values[0]));
        } else {
          cautionValue.html(Math.abs(ui.values[1]) + '-' + Math.abs(ui.values[0]) + 'km/lo');
          $("#minValue").val(Math.abs(ui.values[0]));
          $("#maxValue").val(Math.abs(ui.values[1]));
        }
        console.log(Math.abs(ui.values[0]) + '-' + Math.abs(ui.values[1]) + 'km/lo');
      },

    });
    var val0 = Math.abs(sliderElement1.slider('values', 0));
    var val1 = Math.abs(sliderElement1.slider('values', 1));
    cautionValue.html(val0 + '-' + val1 + 'km/lo');
    $("#minValue").val(val0);
    $("#maxValue").val(val1);
    if (flag === 0) {
      flag = 1;
    } else {
      flag = 0;
    }

  });
});
```

See it in action here: [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eju6k12s/2/)